# Операции с таймером php

Tags: jquery, php, разработка-игр

Добрый вечер! На фоне системного изучения ООП в php хочу попробовать свои силы в написании простой браузерной игры с стиле RTS (стратегии). В качестве движка для хранения информации о пользователях,работы форума, создания и хранения свойств некоторых игровых объектов использую 1С Битрикс. Возник вопрос с реализацией некоторых функций в игре. В частности постройке игровых объектов, войск и улучшения технологий. Я хочу не привязывать пользователя постоянно к игровому процессу, чтобы пользователь мог например запустить разработку технологи (которая в зависимости от ресурсов игрока и ряда других факторов может идти от 0,5 до 3-х часов), разлогинится и ждать уведомления (SMS, E-mail) о завершении процесса разработки. Как можно реализовать подобные функции. Записывать в БД время страта разработки, вычислять и записывать время окончания и затем в момент обращения игрока к "меню технологий" запрашивать из БД эти значения и на основе какого-нибудь jquery плагина рисовать пользователю таймер (http://ruseller.com/lessons/les1341/demo/index.html) или прогресс-бар?

Comment: rts на битриксе ?

Comment: битрикс просто в качестве системы хранения данных о пользователях, работы форумов, соц.модули, подписки, голосования и т.п. Естественно остальные функции касающиеся непосредственно игры работают на отдельных классах и с отдельными таблицами т.к. Bitrix Framework для них слишком медленный.